# Problems catching an exception in c#

Tags: c#, exception, combobox, buttonclick

I have a combobox with two items. I also have a button that opens a new form when one of these items are selected. However if none of the items are selected there is an exception(nullpointer). I have tried (to no avail) to catch this exception and show a mbox that prompts the user to choose one of the items.

Here is the code for the button click even:

```
if (labelGrid.Text == "Member" && cbTable.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Workout"))
        {
            string name;
            string ss;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dtGrid1.SelectedRows)
            {
                ss = dtGrid1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                name = dtGrid1.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
                BookMemberWorkout bmw = new BookMemberWorkout(ss, name);
                bmw.Label2.Text = ss;
                bmw.Label1.Text = name;
                bmw.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see a `try-catch` block, so how are you trying to catch that exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to use exceptions for flow control in non-exceptional cases. The case that the user didn't select anything is surely not exceptional.

The correct approach would be a simple `null` check:

```
if(cbTable.SelectedItem == null)
{
    // Show message box
}
else
{
    // Your current code
}
```

---

<sup>Why your exception handling code isn't working is impossible to answer, because you didn't include it in your question.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the line:

```
ss = dtGrid1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

You can't be sure the value is not null, so you should check it before calling the .ToString().

Instead of using a message box you could use a RequiredValidator to perform javascript validation, avoiding a useless postback.

Answer (score 0):

From performance and readability point-of-view, I'd recommend checking for selected value in the combo box rather than catching an exception, like this

```
if(cbTable.SelectedItem == null)
{
         MessageBox.Show("Please select a value in the combo box.");
         return;
}

if (labelGrid.Text == "Member" && cbTable.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Workout"))
        {
            string name;
            string ss;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dtGrid1.SelectedRows)
            {
                ss = dtGrid1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                name = dtGrid1.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
                BookMemberWorkout bmw = new BookMemberWorkout(ss, name);
                bmw.Label2.Text = ss;
                bmw.Label1.Text = name;
                bmw.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

However to answer your specific query, you can catch [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) like this:

```
 try{
        if (labelGrid.Text == "Member" && cbTable.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Workout"))
        {
            string name;
            string ss;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dtGrid1.SelectedRows)
            {
                ss = dtGrid1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                name = dtGrid1.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
                BookMemberWorkout bmw = new BookMemberWorkout(ss, name);
                bmw.Label2.Text = ss;
                bmw.Label1.Text = name;
                bmw.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(NullReferenceException ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Please select a value in the combo box.");
    }
```

Comment: what I did wrong was trying to catch a "regular" Exception instead of a NullReferenceException

Comment: Even the null reference exception is not an ideal solution because some other part of the code in try block could also throw null ref exception. On a side not, although a bit dated now, I found this quite helpful: http://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/net-exceptions-all-of-them/